# Preservation of tabs (indentation) on jquery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a very basic site that has a `textarea` and a `div`. When text is input in the text area, it gets processed by some JavaScript functions resulting in the final HTML markup

Problem is, tabs (`\t`) are not preserved. Is there a way to do this? Maybe replacing all `\t` by a certain HTML tag (like replacing line breaks with `<br/>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the HTML (`<div>`) element. You won't have to modify the text - it will format itself.

> **pre**
>   Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at
>   newline characters in the source and at 
>  elements.

Comment: You may need to use `pre-wrap` if you're worried about the text overflowing the boundary of the container.

Comment: This is even better haha!

Answer (score 1):

For a code-only solution, replace them with multiple non-break spaces (e.g. `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`) - repeat to suit your indenting level (4 and 8 are spaces are most common).

```
var str = "\tline 1";
str = str.replace(/\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
alert(str);
```

use a regex with `/g` as `replace` with a string does not support multiple matches.

Comment: Awesome! Worked great.